# Python get different error response for commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to get a different error responses for `commands.CheckFailure` in `on_command_error` for different commands.

so this is my `on_command_error`

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "don't have permission")
```

So how to to make it send different response for another command which raises `commands.CheckFailure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`ctx.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.command) to resolve the command that raised the error:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(some_check)
async def kick(ctx):
    ...

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        command = ctx.command    # command = ctx.invoked_with
        if command is bot.kick:  # if command == 'kick':
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "don't have permission to kick")
        elif command is some_other_command:
            ...
        else:
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Generic message")
```

Comment: I getting error `in on_command_error
    if command is kick:
NameError: name 'kick' is not defined`  mostly cozz my `@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):` is in main py file and `kick` command is in seperate file cog.

Comment: Shouldn't the error handling for that be in that cog then? You could try to compare against `bot.kick`, or check `ctx.invoked_with` against `'kick'`

Comment: I using multiple cog files to reduce size. so all `error handling` is kept in main file. and if i have different command in different files i can't add `error handling` in all files. what to do with  `bot.kick` or `check ctx.invoked_with`